# Runtime error when grouping shapes in MS-Word 2010 using a VBA Script

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm trying to write a small VBA-Macro to tidy up a huge word file with a bunch of pictures (>100) by making sure they are all normal shapes (not inline) and have a caption associated with them. Further the caption and the picture need to be grouped together to make re-arranging them easier.

I do however run into problems when running the code. After creating a "shaperange" the "group" method crashes  (`Set shpGroup = ShpRng.Group`) with a runtime error "'-2147024891 (8000700005)': The grouping of selected forms is disabled"

Here's my code:

```
Sub PicFix()
'
' For a selected picture, convert it to a normal image (not inline),
' add acaption to it, then group the image and its caption
'
    Dim sCaption As String
    Dim shpIn As InlineShape
    Dim shpPic, shpCap, shpGroup  As Shape
    Dim ShpRng As ShapeRange
    Dim sNamePic, sNameCap As String
    Dim iZOrder As Integer

'First of all get hold of the shape and assign it to the SHP object
' In case it is an inline shape, converted to a normal shape
    If Selection.InlineShapes.Count > 0 Then
        Set shpIn = Selection.InlineShapes(1)
        Set shpPic = shpIn.ConvertToShape
    Else
        Set shpPic = Selection.ShapeRange(1)
    End If

' Second, fetch the caption text from the clipboard
    ' sCaption = GetClipBoardText()
    ' For debugging purpose....
       sCaption = "This is a dummy caption" ' Just assign a dummy caption string


' now  start to "fix" the selected picture...
shpPic.Select
iZOrder = shpPic.ZOrderPosition
sNamePic = "Pic_" + CStr(iZOrder)
shpPic.Name = sNamePic  ' Give this object a name. Use the ZOrderPosition as a name as it is unique within the documnet
                        ' (but might change as new shapes etc. are addedd to the document - but, best I can do)
shpPic.WrapFormat.Type = wdWrapSquare ' Make the text wraps around all sides

If sCaption > "" Then
    shpPic.Select ' make sure the picture is selected before adding the caption below it
    Selection.InsertCaption Label:="Figure", TitleAutoText:="", Title:=": " + sCaption, Position:=wdCaptionPositionBelow

    ' Now the selected object has changed from the picture to the new caption
    Set shpCap = Selection.ShapeRange(1)
    sNameCap = "Cap_" + CStr(iZOrder)       ' Give the caption object a name as well
    shpCap.Name = sNameCap

    Debug.Print "ShapeNames: shpPic=" + shpPic.Name + "; shpCap=" + shpCap.Name
    Debug.Print "ShapeTypes: shpPic=" + CStr(shpPic.Type) + "; shpCap=" + CStr(shpCap.Type) ' 13=Picture; 17=TextBox

    ' Here is the tricky bit ... group the picture and its caption ...
    ' create a shaperange containing the two objects, then group them
    Set ShpRng = ActiveDocument.Shapes.Range(Array(sNamePic, sNameCap))

    Set shpGroup = ShpRng.Group ' <<<<------ This is where it crashes :
                                '               runtime Error: Grouping of selected objects (or forms) is disabled

    shpGroup.Select ' Make sure it is selected
    shpGroup.WrapFormat = wdWrapSquare ' Make the text wraps around all sides
End If

End Sub
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Try putting a break point on the line that crashes and run it.  When it stops at the break point, type `ShpRange.Select` in the immediate window.  This will select the items that ShpRange refers to in the actual document.  It would be interesting to see if it is what you expect.

Comment: I had the same error message going on, and I noticed that it occurred when I was trying to group shapes on a page where there was no text to anchor the shapes to. A table had wrapped from the previous page, and that's where the error occurred. I'm not convinced that the error message text is actually precise in what is going on, since my code works fine on other documents (smaller test documents with fewer than the big error doc (100 pages, with wrapped tables).

Answer (score 0):

The problem has to do with the caption being selected (or in edit mode or something).

You can work around this issue by selecting something else before the problem code.

```
' Following added to workaround error when caption is selected.
shpPic.Select
Set shpGroup = ShpRng.Group ' <<<<------ This is where it crashes :
```

Note that you get an error with the last line once you solve this problem.  You should change it to:

```
shpGroup.WrapFormat.Type = wdWrapSquare ' Make the text wraps around all sides
```

Comment: Super! Thanks a lot for the quick reply. My Macro is no working properly.